# imagePickerController returns image with 0 bytes

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iPad app where I'm trying to let a user take picture with the camera and then save it to my server. But for some reason, the UIImage returned from

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

returns an image of 0 bytes...

[image: this is what happens when someone clicks use photo]

The weird thing is I can display this image just fine in a UIImageView, but when I try to save it to my server, it sends 0 bytes, so nothing gets saved.

I'm stumped, any ideas?

Thank you so much for any suggestions,

Comment: Please post code in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        UIImage *newImage = [self scaleAndRoateImage:chosenImage];

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: unfortunately, it did the same, both chosenImage and newImage were 0 bytes.

Comment: Strange can you tried 
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0); 
NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);

Answer (score 0):

Apparently dismissing the imageController before accessing the info dictionary solves this problem.

So try

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        UIImage *newImage = [self scaleAndRoateImage:chosenImage];

    }];
}
```

More info:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52639-uiimagepickercontroller-issue-did-i-miss-something.html#post266218

Answer (score 0):

Check in this delegate method:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```